# click through overlay div to canvas with delegating click event over coordinates

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a canvas-application that has no built-in zoom&pan solution.

My workaround is an overlay  over the canvas with pointer-events:all and opacity: 0, so you can zoom and pan around.

My Problem now is to delegate a click from the overlay to the canvas. Now my idea was to take the coordinates of the touch-click and simulate this click again with pointer-events:none but its not working..

```
$(document).on('touchstart', function (event) {
  showCoordinates(event);
});

function showCoordinates(event) {
  var x = event.touches[0].clientX;
  var y = event.touches[0].clientY;
  console.log(x);
  console.log(y);
  $('#overlay').css('pointer-events','none');
  var myEvent = $.Event( "touchstart", { pageX:x, pageY:y } );
  $("body").trigger( myEvent );
  $('#overlay').css('pointer-events','all');
}
```

and my main problem is the part where i simulate the click here

```
var myEvent = $.Event( "touchstart", { pageX:x, pageY:y } );
$("body").trigger( myEvent );
```

it even doesnt work in google chrome console.
What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First problem is that the event you created does not have `event.touches[0].clientX` and `event.touches[0].clientY` props which are used in the `showCoordinates` function. Change

```
var myEvent = $.Event( "touchstart", { pageX:x, pageY:y } );
```

to

```
var myEvent = $.Event( "touchstart", { touches: [{clientX: x, clientY: y}] } );
```

. And in the last line, give values to `x` and `y`. Most probably, you will run into new problems, like infinite recursion. Give some HTML code so you can better help. I guess, there is a simpler solution.